# "Chapter" before chapter number in Tufte classes

Tags: sectioning, chapters, tufte

Is there a way to insert usual "Chapter" before chapter number in Tufte classes, such as "Chapter 1" etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `tufte` classes use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, all that is needed is a small modification to `\titleformat` for `\chapter`, to include `\chaptertitlename` (the original definition can be found in the file `tufte-common.def`):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [display]% shape
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
  {\itshape\huge\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}% before the title body
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]